# What type of paint is this?

Tags: painting, paint

I found this paint on wall of college institute.

Color: Green, It has some *lumps*.

[image: paint]

Comment: The plaster most likely used under the paint is called "calcio vecchio" in many parts of Europe. It makes the wall look old on purpose.

Comment: In English speaking countries it seems it's called [stucco patch or knockdown dash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AF6JVoyI8D4).

Answer (score 1):

Without chemical analysis there is no real way to tell what type of paint that is. It does appear to be several layers thick, the lumps could be due to accumulation and marks from the rollers used to apply it.

Alternatively, it could actually be one layer with a type of plaster mixed in to make it thick and applied with a textured roller that makes the surface you see.

One way to find out is to sand an area about a foot long with a medium light abrasive paper. Start at one end of the one foot section and fade the sanding by getting sanding harder and more to the other side. You should see the layers appear like a topographical map.

Drew K